# Command-line tool to query Wikidata (or another SPARQL endpoint)

Tags: linux, open-source, command-line, wikidata, sparql

In the Linux terminal, I want to run a SPARQL query, and get as output the result as CSV:

```
$ query --service https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=SPARQL --sparql "SELECT ?i ?c WHERE { ?i wdt:P31 wd:Q3917681. ?i wdt:P137 ?c.}"
wd:Q4374016,wd:Q819
wd:Q4374028,wd:Q711
wd:Q4374063,wd:Q874
wd:Q4374039,wd:Q159
```

... or something similar.

Requirements:

- Free, open source
- Works with Wikidata
- Works on Linux
- Bonus if it can handle usual namespace prefixes without having to specify them on command line.
- Having to write the request in a text file is acceptable too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote [this bash script](https://github.com/database-of-embassies/database-of-embassies/blob/ca7cc1cd8249062c6bbaf6785545a540ab985848/tools/query-wikidata.sh) to allow easy Wikidata queries from command line.

Usage:

```
./query-wikidata.sh "SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {?item wdt:P31 wd:Q3917681. ?item wdt:P137 wd:Q16. ?item wdt:P131*/wdt:P17 wd:Q142.}"
```

OR this more readable syntax:

```
echo "
 SELECT DISTINCT
   ?item
 WHERE {
   ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q3917681.
   ?item wdt:P137 wd:Q16.
   ?item wdt:P131*/wdt:P17 wd:Q142.
 }
 " |./query-wikidata.sh
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<sparql xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#'>
        <head>
                <variable name='item'/>
        </head>
        <results>
                <result>
                        <binding name='item'>
                                <uri>http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q137798</uri>
                        </binding>
                </result>
        </results>
</sparql>
```

Plus some network information on error output.

It knows the standard Wikidata prefixes.
License: GNU-GPLv3

Comment: link to script is broken as of 2022-02-12

Comment: @wolfgang fahl: Fixed, thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 4):

For most applications the basic command-line approach is enough. Given the query in a file `query.sparql`, get CSV with curl:

```
curl -X POST https://query.wikidata.org/sparql -H "Accept: text/csv" --data-urlencode query@query.sparql
```

Here is [another bash script](https://gist.github.com/nichtich/140ac06a83c6cfbbbb46107c2d4d4a79) that also supports JSON output, for instance to  process with `jq`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Run a Wikidata query from command line
# 
# Usage examples:
#
#   wdquery "DESCRIBE wd:Q42"
#   wdquery - xml < query.sparql
#   wdquery query.sparql json
#

QUERY=${1--}        # SPARQL query or file
FORMAT=${2-json}    # output format

ENDPOINT=https://query.wikidata.org/sparql

# make sure query is written to a file
if ! [ -f "$QUERY" ]
then
    TMPFILE="$(mktemp)"
    if [ "$QUERY" == "-" ]
    then
        # read query from STDIN
        cat > "$TMPFILE"
    else
        # write query to file
        echo "$QUERY" > "$TMPFILE"
    fi
    QUERY="$TMPFILE"
fi

curl -s -X GET -F "query=@$QUERY" "$ENDPOINT?format=$FORMAT"

[ -z "$TMPFILE" ] || rm "$TMPFILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't recognize Wikidata prefixes by default, and can't output CSV at the moment, but the [RDF4J Console](http://rdf4j.org/doc/rdf4j-server-workbench-and-console/rdf4j-console/) is a useful generic commandline application, not just for talking to Wikidata, but to any public SPARQL endpoint, your own RDF4J Server, or even a simple embedded triplestore of your own.

To install, you need a Java (8) Runtime Environment. Then, just [download the RDF4J SDK](http://rdf4j.org/download). The `console.sh` script can be found in the `bin/` directory.

To query Wikidata, start the console and add a new SPARQL endpoint definition:

```
./console.sh 
Connected to default data directory
RDF4J Console 2.0.1
Type 'help' for help.
> create sparql
Please specify values for the following variables:
SPARQL query endpoint: https://query.wikidata.org/sparql
SPARQL update endpoint: 
Local repository ID [endpoint@localhost]: wikidata
Repository title [SPARQL endpoint repository @localhost]: wikidata sparql endpoint
Repository created
```

Once that's set up, you can open the created repository (which is just a proxy for the public SPARQL endpoint):

```
> open wikidata
Opened repository 'wikidata'
```

Then just query (taking care not to overload the endpoint - use `limit` clauses if you're experimenting):

```
wikidata> select * where {?x rdf:type ?o } limit 10
Evaluating SPARQL query...
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| x                                   | o                                   |
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| <http://wikiba.se/ontology#Dump>    | <http://schema.org/Dataset>         |
| <http://www.wikidata.org/value/8000b1b66dfb1c74420cf59f0388d425>| <http://wikiba.se/ontology#GeoAutoPrecision>|
| <http://www.wikidata.org/value/8000d3ac475ff41c5e2e38ffda574d1c>| <http://wikiba.se/ontology#GeoAutoPrecision>|
| <http://www.wikidata.org/value/8000f71177f50273969eca2096803e29>| <http://wikiba.se/ontology#GeoAutoPrecision>|
| <http://www.wikidata.org/value/80018edb4bf3ecf344a2d4343d76235c>| <http://wikiba.se/ontology#GeoAutoPrecision>|
| <http://www.wikidata.org/value/800269618da5a8571140652500ade834>| <http://wikiba.se/ontology#GeoAutoPrecision>|
| <http://www.wikidata.org/value/8003743c7dbef48511f9df4e629fd462>| <http://wikiba.se/ontology#GeoAutoPrecision>|
| <http://www.wikidata.org/value/8003a8ceaf4f75884d2b9ff99e3c959c>| <http://wikiba.se/ontology#GeoAutoPrecision>|
| <http://www.wikidata.org/value/80062f03a3a91733e0eb81f50ca56208>| <http://wikiba.se/ontology#GeoAutoPrecision>|
| <http://www.wikidata.org/value/800682cb1e9157517ed01b1a4b1760bc>| <http://wikiba.se/ontology#GeoAutoPrecision>|
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
10 result(s) (1231 ms)
```

The above is all done interactively, but of course you can script these commands and then just feed them into the `console.sh` shellscript.

FWIW, output format specification [is on the ToDO list](https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j/issues/603), as is the [custom definition of namespaces](https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j/issues/604).

Regarding your requirements, point by point:

- RDF4J is open source ([EDL license](https://www.eclipse.org/org/documents/edl-v10.php))
- It works with Wikidata or any other SPARQL endpoint
- Works on Linux or any other OS (Java)
- Does not (yet) support handling namespace prefixes without having to specify them (at least not for SPARQL endpoints)
- You don't *have* to write the request in a text file, but you can if you want

Answer (score 1):

There is a Perl-based commandline tool `wdq` from 2016, available from the Debian/Ubuntu repos (`apt install wdq`, on [Github](https://github.com/nichtich/wdq#readme) and on [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::wdq).

A shell command like this:

```
# option -t means 
# call the label-service for the ?planet variable.

wdq -tplanet '?planet wdt:P31 wd:Q44559; wdt:P397 ?sun' \
  > stars-and-exoplanets.json`
```

will be transformed to a SPARQL query and you'll  get a JSON resultset back.

You won't have to specify namespace prefixes; and `wdq` also injects the label-Service into the SPARQL query. Read the [post on OpenData.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/7153/5763) by User *Jakob*.

You can transform JSON to CSV with`jq`.

compact:

```
< stars-and-exoplanets.json jq -r    \
  '.[] | map(.) | @csv' \
  > stars-and-exoplanets.csv
```

More verbose (with hardcoded column headers)

```
< stars-and-exoplanets.json jq -r    \
'. | map({"p":.planet, "pl":.planetLabel,  "pd":.planetDescription, "sun":.sun})'  \
 | jq -r '(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv' \
> stars-and-exoplanets.csv
```

JSON:

```
# < stars-and-exoplanets.json jq  '.[0]'
# first record of ~3000
{
  "planet": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1198042",
  "planetDescription": "extrasolar planet",
  "planetLabel": "HD 37124 d",
  "sun": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q139390"
}
```

CSV (first 2 lines):

```
# < sun-and-stars-and-exoplanets.csv head -2

"p","pd","pl","sun"
"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1198042","extrasolar planet","HD 37124 d","http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q139390"
#...many more
```

`wdq` can also pretty-print SQPARQL queries with the `--no-execute` option.

##### Update 2023: `wikidata-cli`

There is also the `wikidata-cli` program, a NodeJS application. See [github repo](https://github.com/maxlath/wikibase-cli). It is more actively maintained and -according to the documentation- a semi-official app (supported by Wikipedia project grants)